# I don't get how tuple unpacking works (Python-2.x)

Tags: python, python-2.7, iterable-unpacking

as I was wondering how tuple unpacking was working, I've found on several threads this answer as an alternative to slicing :

```
>>>>def unpack(first,*rest):
    return first, rest
```

which works as follows:

```
>>>>first,rest=unpack(*(1,2,3))
>>>>first
1
>>>>rest
(2,3)
```

I don't understand how the * works. The argument "first" isn't supposed to be given to my function unpack ? I thought * meant that the argument was optional.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You are mixing concepts here. The return value of `unpack()` is being unpacked into `first` and `rest` (tuple unpacking). The `unpack()` function signature has a splat-syntax catch-all argument `rest`. And thirdly, you are using a function call feature to expand a sequence into positional arguments. **These are 3 separate things**.

Comment: Yes I understood I was using a function call feature. What I hadn't understood was that unpack(*(1,2,3)) was equivalent to unpack(1,2,3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*` in a function definition doesn't mean optional; it means "pack any additional (non-keyword) arguments the caller supplied into a tuple and put the tuple here". Similarly, `*` on a function call means "unpack this sequence of things and supply all the elements as arguments to the function individually."

```
unpack(*(1,2,3))
```

unpacks `(1,2,3)` and calls

```
unpack(1,2,3)
```

`1` is assigned to `first`, and the remaining arguments `2` and `3` are packed into a tuple and assigned to `rest`.

Comment: This is even clearer than the answer above ! I didn't realise there was a difference between
    *
in a function definition and
   *
in a function call. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

In your case, `unpack(*(1,2,3))` is just `unpack(1, 2, 3)`.

Implementation of unpack takes the first argument, and an args tale, then returns it as a tuple.

Star syntax is useful, if you would pass arguments as a variable:

```
a = (1, 2, 3)
first, rest = unpack(*a)
```

Comment: Ok I get it, thank you. I didn't realize these two were equivalent, the second formulation is clearer.